# My custom uitableviewcell is very to scroll in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom UITableViewCell which is made from nib file and contain large imageView ( use SDWebImage) , OHAttributedLabel  and 5-6 UILabel

The scroll is normal and rather quick in iOS6 but in iOS7 , it turns out to be very slow and lagging.

I tried to remove some elements in the nib file and notice that it is very slow to scroll when having either large imageView (SDWebImage) or OHAttributedLabel

Are there any ways I can do to improve scrolling performance ? It was good in iOS6 so I didn't expect to have this problem before ( I use iphone5 for testing)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

  //register the nib here for customItemCEll 
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customItemCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customItemCell"];
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customItemCell";

   CustomItemCell *cell = (CustomItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SquakCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

customItem *item = [itemsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item post] ]];


    [attrStr setFontName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

// cell.postLabel is OHAtrributedLabel
    cell.postLabel.delegate = self;
    cell.postLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
    cell.postLabel.text = [item post] ;

  //configureHashtage is too ask OHAttributedLabel to make a hashtag link
    [cell configureHashtagLabel];


    if([item hasImageURLString]){


        [cell.postImageView setHidden:NO];
        CGFloat yPosition = cell.thumbnailView.frame.origin.y + cell.thumbnailView.frame.size.height+15;

  NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]};
        CGRect frameSize = [item.post boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(220, 2000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];



        yPosition = MAX(yPosition,cell.postLabel.frame.origin.y+frameSize.size.height+20);
        [cell.postImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item postImageURLString]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_placeholder.png"] ];
       CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(10 ,yPosition, 300, 200);
        [cell.postImageView setFrame:imageFrame];
        [cell.postImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        cell.postImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [cell.postImageView setupImageViewerWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item postImageURLString]]];


    }
    else {
        [cell.postImageView setHidden:YES];
    }




    return cell;



}
```

Comment: Might be worth looking into caching the images. The image request class here helped my collection view (I realise you are using a tableview but im sure it can be translated across, I also realise you havent stated if youre downloading the images or not) http://www.pressingquestion.com/4736540/Poor-Uicollectionview-Scrolling-Performance-With-Uiimage

Comment: Images are already cached by using SDWebImage , so I don't think that is the case. And even if I remove the imageView , it is still very slow to scroll.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Ah ok - I've never used that. Probably should have read up before I commented. Youve posted no code though, how much work are you doing in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Are you reusing the cells or creating a new one each time? Reuse makes a huge difference.

Comment: I am using custom UITableViewCell. So it means that I reuse the cell. Please sell my code above

Answer (score 0):

I had a huge performance impact on my table scrolling performance on iOS 7, and I tracked it down to this line of code:

```
[UISearchBar appearance].backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

It turns out, this line of code doesn't do anything anyway - and it was put in by mistake when I was customising the look of my iOS 7 app.

It must be a bug in the SDK, but by removing this line and re-running my app, my scroll performance resolved itself - this was all scroll views in the app. It must have been doing something on the main run loop that was stealing cpu cycles... I don't know if that even makes sense.

Anyway... you could always check and see if you have any appearance code, and comment it out temporarily to find what is killing your performance.

Comment: Thanks , I will try that . Did you put that code in cellForRowAtIndexPath  ?

Comment: My point was, DON'T use that code. I was suggesting an area you might look into. I do any global appearance customisations on app launch, not int cellForRowAtIndexPath - which is just for returning cells for an indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular `UILabel`. iOS 6 and 7 support `NSAttributedString` out of the box. In iOS 6 it uses WebKit, but in iOS 7 it uses Text Kit. The iOS 7 version of `UILabel` should be significantly optimized.

Comment: Thanks, I tried UILabel but the performance is still the same. I found that the problem occur when the text display is not English and more than one line.  The drawTextInRect consumes a lot of resource and make the scrolling lag.

Comment: same here, I just realise that on ios7, if the uilabel has text that not in english, the drawing is very slow at cause the scroll to lag. drawTextInRect.